# Can I login with two different Facebook accounts on one app? (Winforms)

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

I built an app on Winforms that finds common interests between two Facebook users, and so I need to have two users logged in at the same time, I tried working like this:

```
            m_User1Result = FacebookService.Login("#myappid#", "public_profile",
               "user_friends",
               etc..
               );
            m_User2Result = FacebookService.Login("#myappid#", "public_profile",
               "user_friends",
               etc..
               );
```

but what it does is logging in the first user twice. Any advices?
EDIT: FacebookService is a public class that we have to use (this is a college assignment) and it has static methods that help us use the Facebook API.

Comment: What is `FacebookService`? Is it a static class or is it an instance of some other class?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, it's a part of "FacebookWrapper" that we have to use (college assignment), it's a public class with lots of static methods that helps us use the Facebook API.

Comment: You could possibly try declaring two instances of `FacebookService` and logging in with those, thus creating two separate sessions.

Comment: I can create two instances of FacebookService, but since the methods are static I can't use them using those instances

Comment: You can not log in two users in the same app instance at the same time, that just doesn’t make any sense. You need to have them login individually, to grant your app the necessary permissions. And after that, you go via the currently logged in user’s social context to see what likes they have in common with a different user of your app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/mutual_likes/